# css dotted border with half cirlces

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to create a dotted border like in this image:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZshU.jpg

```
  .pinnwand-header {
    background-color: #54BC81;
    border-top: dotted 0.33rem #54BC81;
    border-left:  dotted 0.33rem #54BC81;
    border-right:  dotted 0.33rem #54BC81;
}
  .pinnwand-inner {
    background-color: #54BC81;
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-top: -2px;
  }
```

I tried to overlapping the dots with an inner layer to cut the circles of the border in half. Then I got problems with gaps between the borders. Is there a better approach to achieve this?